# Math.random() is not working in browser in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, backend

I am writing this code in node but Math.random() is not working in the browser when I hit the address it shows an error but in cmd it's working fine i.e. comsole.log(x).

the error is[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiGvP.png)

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    console.log("Someone Requested Us!");
    res.send("You've Reached The Home Page"); //res.write("Hello World");
    res.end();
});

app.get("/random_num",function(req,res){
    const x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1 ;
    console.log(x);
    res.send(x);
    //res.end();
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server Running On 3000");
});
```

Comment: It seems like the error message is telling you what to do :) To use `res.sendStatus()` instead of `res.send(x)`. ...and that is happening because you're sending a number, so express thinks you're sending back just a http status code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the error messages as text, not as image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[res.send([Body])](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.send) does not expect a number to be sent.

> The body parameter can be a Buffer object, a String, an object, Boolean, or an Array.

Looking at your error, it looks like earlier numbers were allowed and were implicitly used as `HTTP Status Codes` (eg: 200,404,201). Now, express is thinking you are still using the old syntax from the versions when sending status code using `.send()` was normal. Now it is deprecated. Anyway, 8 is not a valid code.

You can do:

```
res.send({'random' : x });
```

Your error also lets you know that you can simply use res.sendStatus(200) etc. if you want to send status. You probably do not want that though.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with the random instead you are returning response in wrong way.

```
res.sendStatus(200).json(x)
```